# How to properly use python async functionality

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, parallel-processing

I hardly understand the python async, and how to use it properly when there is multiple functions on the await. For example, I have two models:

- In model A, function #3 should await function#2 that should await function#1
- In model B, there is a two independent branched functions (maybe work in parallel).

I would be grateful, if anyone explain the async, through solving the two models.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Python async (and the asyncio library) is a way in Python to have multiple executions of code running concurrently. Concurrently means there is only one thread running your program, but asyncio is switching the line of execution between your concurrently running code blocks.

Asyncio is great for IO bound applications for this reason. For example, in model B, say Func 4 takes a long time waiting for a web response. In this time, the CPU is doing very little. In this case asyncio will transfer control over to Func 2 to run it until the web response returns. This concurrent execution is achieved with the [asyncio.create_task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) function.

Your model A is also a valid asyncio program, but it doesn't utilize async's strength of efficiently utilizing IO downtime.